# Is there a way to change an event action name in Google Analytics 3?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, data-analysis

I'm trying to change the event actions name in Google Aalytics 3, is there a way to do this?

For example change from "25" to "25%" and from "play" to "Play".

[image: Screenshot of the actions I want to rename]

Comment: To be clear there is Universal analytics and google analytics ga4 there is no Google Analytics v3.

Answer (score 0):

Once hits have been sent to Google analytics this data is there for good.   There is now way to update it.

Comment: Im not trying to update the values that where sent, i want to update the names from the field “Event Actions”

Comment: The GA3 platform doesn't have this kind of feature you are looking for. You only can modify from where this event been sent. GTM or the Gtag code.